# R: GLMM on RNA-Seq count data

Tags: r, glmm

I would like to use GLMM on RNA-Seq data (counts) using negative binomial distribution in R to identify deferentially expressed genes. Does anyone know of any resources, tutorials or how to go about doing this?

Comment: Joseph Hilbe's book *Negative Binomial Regression* (Cambridge, 2007) is probably the single best resource.